# CSS relative url to images

Tags: css, path

I am developing on my localhost - http://localhost/mysite, and within that I have the following directory structure:

```
-assets
--css
---styles.css
--images
---background.png
```

Within the styles.css file, I would have something the following, which works fine on localhost

```
background-image: url(../images/background.png);
```

However, the live server works off a subdomain - http://test.liveserver.com. This means that the css rule has to change as follows:

```
background-image: url(/assets/images/loginlogo.png);
```

Not sure on the best way to get around this?

Comment: Right, for some reason, cssmin seems to be prepending a url when the css is minified on the live server. So, url(../images/background.png); becomes  url(/test/assets/images/background.png); I need to investigate more

Comment: Bah, it appears that cssmin was indeed prepending a url when it did not need to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the directory tree you are providing you don't have to change your path.

`..` means the parent directory of the CSS file so the `assets/` directory is implied.