# How do I display an image via CSS in my local environment?

Tags: html, css, local

This is quite embarrasing.  I am learning new things but I am surprised I can't figure this out on my own.

On my desktop, I have a folder called Test and in that I have `index.html` and a folder called CSS, which contains `index.css` and another folder called images with an image called `logo.png`.

In my `index.css` file, I have the following line:

```
background: url("images/logo.png") no-repeat;
```

Using the above line I can't display the image locally.  I tried using `/images` and `test/images` but it doesn't work.  How can I display this if I am viewing it locally?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384299/css-relative-url-to-images .. look up relative URL paths.. you will want `"../images/logo.png"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned, you have different folders for CSS and images inside your root folder `Test`. Since you are writing code for `background` in your CSS file:

**Case 1:**

```
background:url("logo.png");
```

Will search for your image inside `CSS` folder.

---

**Case2:**

```
background:url("images/logo.png");
```

Will search for `images` folder first inside CSS folder and then will search for `logo.png` inside that `images` folder. (But there is no images folder inside your CSS folder).

---

**Case3:**

```
background: url("../images/logo.png") no-repeat;
```

In this case `..` will take you back to the main directory (i.e. from `css` folder to your root forder `Test`. Then `/images` will take you inside `images` folder and it will find `/logo.png` as a path to your image.)

Comment: That worked.  Never seen the usage of dots before the folder name.  Why is that?

Comment: @ariel Please mark this answer correct so that there will be no more duplicate answers. Thank you

Comment: .. goes back a directory. You called the image in the css directory, which it wasn't in.

Answer (score 3):

Change img to the name of your class. Use content instead of background or background-image, and Set some width.

```
img {
     content: url("../img/Wizard-of-os-black.png");
     width: 90px;
}
```

Comment: how is this a bad negative answer?

Comment: Maybe because you've misspelt 'Oz'?

Comment: Very nice. I fiddled with background and background-image, had to set width and height and had a thin border even with border=0 padding=0 0 0 0 and margin=0 0 0 0. Now I just need a class, display block and margin 0 auto 0 auto to display a logo centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this to

```
background-image: url("images/logo.png") no-repeat;
```

Comment: he has `image` in one folder and `css`  in another folder.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would have to think logically. If your in a CSS file in contained within a folder, all links in the file are searched in the folder. If you want to link to an image in a folder called /img in the root of your site, you would have to move up a level by using

```
../img/pic.extension
```